# ArcGIS Field Calculator nested elif is None not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I am calculating a field based on two other fields in ArcMap 10.2 using python.

My Pre-Logic Script Code is

> def myfunc(legend,Btype):
>
> ```
> if(legend == 'Apple'):
>     return 'Banana'
> elif(legend == 'Cranberry'):
>     return 'Date'
> elif(legend == 'Elderberry'):
>     if(Btype.startswith('Fig')):
>         return 'Grape'
>     elif(Btype.startswith('Lychee')):
>         return 'Mango'
>     elif Btype is None:
>         return 'Olive'
>     else:
>         return 'Pear'
> else:
>     return 'Raspberry'
> ```

Mostly this function works, however in the case that legend is "Elderberry" and Btype is "Null" the function returns "Null" rather than "Olive"

The problem only occurs when I nest the "is None" in the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your "is None" check up to the first evaluation.

```
if Btype is None:
  return 'Olive'
elif (Btype.startswith('Fig')):
  return 'Grape'
elif(Btype.startswith('Lychee')):
  return 'Mango'
```

Basically, if Btype is null, you can't do .startswith, etc. on it.